# Different results when Matlab is executed by Windows cmd

Tags: matlab, cmd

I try to figure out how to use Matlab by the Windows `cmd`-promt and I get stucked because of a mysterious behavior.

For testing I have the following function-file:

```
function [ x y ] = testmath( u,v )

x = u*v;
y = u/v;

display(x);
display(y);

end
```

When I execute this in Matlab prompt I get the correct results:

```
[x y] = testmath(2,2)
>> x = 4
>> y = 1
```

Now I want to run the function by the `cmd`:

```
matlab -sd myCurrentDirectory -r "testmath 2 2" -nodesktop -nosplash
```

and I get:

```
x = 2500;
y = 1;
```

Can you reproduce it? What can be the reason? Did I made a mistake by passing the parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Windows `cmd` version, you are calling it with two character arguments (`'2'`) because you forgot the parenthesis. The correct version would be:

```
matlab -sd myCurrentDirectory -r "testmath(2,2)" -nodesktop -nosplash
```

Reproduce the "odd" result on the MATLAB command prompt:

```
>> [x, y] = testmath 2 2
x = 
    2500
y = 
    1

>> [x, y] = testmath(2,2)
x = 
    4
y = 
    1
```

The outcome is 2500, because the ASCII code for the character `'2'` is 50. MATLAB uses this number when applying the multiplication operator to one or two characters.

This is called [function/command duality](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_prog/command-vs-function-syntax.html); arguments passed without parenthesis are interpreted as strings. Same as

```
>> disp hello
hello

>> disp('hello')
hello
```

or

```
>> load myFile.dat 
>> load('myFile.dat')
```

it can be convenient, and confusing (as you just noticed :)